# Aws Datapipeline: List content of Output Bucket in ShellCommandActivity

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

How can I list the files which are contained in my output Bucket in a Shell Script?
ls ${OUTPUT1_STAGING_DIR}
does not work, as I get the message that there's no file or directory by this name.
I am sure there is an easy way to do this but I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience using DataPipeline, that is not supported. You can only read from input bucket directory. The output bucket directory is just a place where you can write files to that will later on be copied over into S3.

Comment: This answer was confirmed by Amazon. Thank you!